# How to get a part of url? (nginx, rewrite, lua)

Tags: nginx, lua, url-rewriting

How to get a part of url?

For example:
have url: /aaa/bbb/ccc?test=123

I need to get part of url /ccc into the nginx variable.

I want to get a variable with a value = "ccc"

I will use the variable in location {}

Comment: It depends where you want to use the variable. If it's inside a `location` block, you mat be able to use a regular expression `location` to capture the part of the URI you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
url  = '/abc/def/ghi?test=123'
-- here ^  to here  ^  then back 1

q = url :find('?')
head = url :sub( 1,  q -1 )  --  /abc/def/ghi

--  reversing is just an easy way to grab what would
--  would be the last delimiter, but is now the first.

head = head :reverse()  --  ihg/fed/cba/
slash = head :find('/') -- 1st ^

--  same as above, grab from beginning, to found position -1

folder = head :sub( 1, slash -1 )  --  ihg
folder = folder :reverse()  --  ghi

--  reverse again, so it's right-way 'round again.
```

---

Commands can be stacked, to make it smaller.  Harder
to explain the logic that way, but it's the same thing.

```
head = url :sub( 1, url :find('?') -1 ) :reverse()
folder = head :sub( 1, head :find('/') -1 ) :reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a [library](https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-reqargs), available from official OpenResty Package Manager `OPM`:

```
opm install bungle/lua-resty-reqargs
```

This library works for both `GET` and `POST` variables:

```
local get, post, files = require "resty.reqargs"()
if not get then
  local ErrorMessage = post
  error(ErrorMessage)
end

-- Here you basically have `get' which is a table with:
-- { test = 123 }
```

The API is a little bit weird because the function returns 3 values.
In case of failure, it will return `false, ErrorMessage, false`.
In case of success, it will return `GetTable, PostTable, FilesTable`. Except this, it just works.

You can use it in a location block:

```
location /aaa/bbb/ccc {
  content_by_lua_block {
    local get, post, files = require "resty.reqargs"()
    if not get then
      local ErrorMessage = post
      ngx.say(ErrorMessage)
    else
      ngx.say(string.format("test=%d", get.test))
    end
  }
}
```